# Visual Studio Android emulator won´t run 64bit app

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, android-emulator, visual-studio-emulator

I am pretty new to Xamarin. I made in VS 2019 Android 10 Emulator on architecture x86_64. The OS running here fine. I need to install some additional apps, but those apps natively developed in 64bit cannot be installed here.

Is there a need to set some additional setting in the emulator app to I can install native 64bit app in the virtual device Google play?

I used default settings of Visual Studio. I just increase the RAM - see attached images with my settings.

[image]
[image]

Thank you for any idea.

Comment: "...native 64bit app..." : Arm or x86 native?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded new images Intel x86 Atom_64 for Android 11 to my VS Studio emulator and now it seems it works fine.

I don´t know where was the problem with Android 10 images, but now I can test the 64bit apps.

Comment: To enable the architecture x86_64, try the following step: Right click the project -> Properties -> Android Options -> Advanced -> Supported architectures, to select the architecture you want.